# extracting substring between two '\n' characters into a seperate array

Tags: c++

I have a 100 char string with few '\n' characters in it , I want to extract the characters between the first '\n' and the second '\n' and store them in another char array , how can i do that?

please note that i cant use iostreams or vectors as I am using AVR GCC. i can only use strok() or strcpy()

Comment: A simple way is to put the text in an `istringstream` and use `getline` from the `<string>` header.

Comment: I think the answer  you seek is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If to use character arrays then you can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char s[100] = "begin\nmiddle\nend";
    char t[100];
    t[0] = '\0';

    if ( char *p = strchr( s, '\n' ) )
    {
        if ( char *q = strchr( ++p, '\n' ) )
        {
            std::strncpy( t, p, q - p );
            t[q - p] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy( t, p );
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\"" << t << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
"middle"
```

If you want to get an array of strings separated by the new line character then you can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    char s[100] = "begin\nmiddle\nend";
    std::istringstream is( s );

    std::vector<std::string> v( ( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ) ),
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );

    for ( const std::string &item : v ) std::cout << '\"' << item << '\"' << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
"begin"
"middle"
"end"
```

But it does not make great sense to use this approach if you need just to copy one substring from one character array to another.

Comment: problem is I dont have iostreams or vectors in AVR GCC ,i need a solution using either strcpy or strok

Comment: hi Vlad  I am not seeing any solution without iostream , I cant use this construct in AVR GCC .

Comment: @AhmadS What is the problem? In my answer there are two demonstrative programs and the first one is what you need.

Comment: hi Vlad you are using #include <iostream> right?                                                        i cant use it

Comment: @AhmadS It is used only to output the resulted string. It does not influence on the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

A basic Version is this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

void base_ansi_c()
{
    const char * source = "one\ntwo\nthree\n";
    char target[1024];
    const char * c;
    for (c = source; c && *c != 0 && *c != '\n'; ++c); //skip until first '\n'
    if (c && *c == '\n') ++c; // skip '\n'
    int n = 0;
    for (; c && *c != 0 && *c != '\n' && n < 1024; ++c, ++n) //copy until second '\n'
    {
        target[n] = *c;
    }
    target[n] = 0;
    cout << "'"  << target << "'\n";
}

void base_cpp_sstream()
{
    std::vector<string> cpp_array;
    std::string test = "one\ntwo\nthree\n";
    std::istringstream is(test);

    std::string part;

    while (std::getline(is, part, '\n'))
    {
        cpp_array.emplace_back(part);
        std::cout << "  " << part << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "The second element is: '" << cpp_array.at(1) << "'\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\nbase_cpp_sstream\n";
    base_cpp_sstream();
    std::cout << "\nbase_ansi_c\n";
    base_ansi_c();
}
```

If it gets more complex you may want to switch to either `boost::tokenizer` or `boost::spirit::qi`.

Since you asked for a different version where the positions are more relevant to the algorithm I added an ansi-c style iterating through the string.

Edit: Some detail about the code above as you requested in the comment. I think explaining this line `for (c = source; c && *c != 0 && *c != '\n'; ++c);` will be enough to get you started.

The statement `c = source` just copies the pointer at the beginning of the loop.

At every iteration including the first the following is checked: `c && *c != 0 && *c != '\n'` The detail here is that `c` will be dereferenced so it can not be `(char*)0`. `0` is `false`, every other value is `true`. If c is false the chained together values using `&&` are not evaluated. So there is no risk of dereferencing a null pointer. `*c != 0` checks if the end of the c-string is reached. In that case no `\n` was found. `*c != '\n'` checks if a new line character is reached.

At the end of an iteration the pointer is incremented. `++c` this moves the `c` pointer to the next element of the array. Since c is a char the pointer is incremented by 1. `sizeof(char)` evaluates to 1. (always). If the array elements were of a different type the increment would also move the pointer to the next element. (does not work with void*).

If `'\n'` is found there is no increment afterwards. The for loop just ends. since c was declared outside of the loop the value remains preserved and can be used by the subsequent algorithms.

Comment: basically i need the position of the first occurance of '\n' which i can get using strchr() but how do i get the second occurence of '\n\ ?

Comment: oh now i see your asnwer , thanks a lot, how does it work can you please explain ?                                                     void base_ansi_c()